# Como generar numeros aleatorios que incrementen su probabilidad luego de ser generados

Tags: java, random, bluej

tengo el siguiente codigo que me crea una matriz un tamaño predefinido y la llena con espacios vacios

```
public class Juego
```

{

```
String tablero[][]= new String[15][35];

public Juego()
{
    for( int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++){
          for( int j = 0; j < tablero[i].length; j++){
                tablero[i][j]  = " "; 
          }
      }
```

necesito llenar la matriz con un asterisco por columna que reciba su posicion de manera aleatoria pero que tenga un orden que debe verse como "montañas"(que la altura del siguiente sea maximo una posicion mas alta o mas baja). Pero lo que no se como hacer es lo siguiente: necesito que si el nivel sube o baja en el siguiente asterisco sea mas probable que en el proximo suba o baje, por ejemplo que si el asterisco siguiente salio mas alto que anterior sea mas posible que el proximo tambien suba. Disculpen si no me logro explicar bien pues hago lo mejor q puedo.

Actualmente jugando con un arreglo de probabilidades obtengo algo asi
[image: resultado]

con el siguiente codigo

```
public void generarAsteriscos()
{   int i=14;
    int j=0;
    tablero[i][j]="*";

    while(j<=33 && i>0)
    {   
        int p=definirPosi();
        if(i+p<0){
            j++;
            i++;
            tablero[i][j]="*";
        }else if(i-p==15){
            j++;

            tablero[i][j]="*";
        }else{
            j++;
            tablero[i-p][j]="*";
            i=i-p;
        }
    }
}
public int definirPosi()// define donde va el proximo asterisco
{
    int[] probabilidades=new int[100];
    int cont=0;
    while(cont<99)
    {   
        probabilidades[cont]=cont;
        cont++;
    }
    int resultado=(int) (1+ Math.random()*100);
    if(resultado==100){
        resultado--;
    }
    if(probabilidades[resultado]>=0 && probabilidades[resultado]<=40)
    {
        return 1;
    }else if(probabilidades[resultado]>50 && probabilidades[resultado]<=80)
    {
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
```

pero como notaran las probabilidades siempre seran las mismas por lo cual va a tender a subir, necesito que sea mas equilibrado que suba y baje o se mantenga pero que no genere algo como

```
*   *   *  **
 *  *  *    ***
```

tiene que generar algo aleatorio que siga un formato similar a este con respecto a las "montañas"

[image: montaña de asteriscos]

Comment: Yo lo veo de la siguiente manera: el porcentaje inicial es (subir)50% - (bajar)50%, bien, tan sólo tienes que guardar la posición del último punto pintado y el penúltimo, si la posición del último punto es mayor que la del penúltimo, modificas la probabilidad por ejemplo en un (subir)60% - (bajar)40%. No sé si me he explicado bien. Saludos!!

Comment: Que distribución de probabilidad siguen los números que estas generando? Si no sabes me imagino que usas random() de java, que sigue la distribución uniforme. Si es así debes de hacer pruebas de aceptación y rechazo para esa distribución y después puedes intentar usar esta ecuación  http://tesis.ipn.mx/jspui/bitstream/123456789/6255/1/IF2.47.pdf pag. 48 del pdf o pag 35 de la numeración. En el punto numero 5, esa es la ecuación que debes programar. La correlación es la R cuadrada de la gráfica de la pagina anterior. En la pagina siguiente viene un ejemplo de código en visual basic.

Comment: @abrahamhs muy interesante tu sugerencia, voy a tratar de hacerla y si estoy utilizando  Math.random()

Comment: @HéctorJ.OrihuelaRuiz es una buena idea tengo que tratar con incrementos en el porcentaje mas bajo y añadir una manera que haga que bajen ya que no debo llegar al tope de la matriz

Comment: Muchas gracias por los comentarios